# kind of X / kinds of X / kinds of Xs

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

> Among various **kind of sports / kinds of sports / kinds of sport,** I like soccer the best.

Which one is correct? Is there any rule implying that one of them has to be singular between 'kind' and 'sports' if the other one is plural and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

> Among various kinds of sports, I like soccer the best.

This would be correct, because you are talking about multiple kinds, and multiple sports. That said, the sentence still isn't correct, because soccer is a sport, not a kind of sport. For example there are outdoor sports, indoor sports, water sports, field sports, and boring sports. They are types of sports. On the other hand soccer, baseball, basketball, and tennis are examples of specific sports.